# Display list in select option Django using JsonResponse?

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

I have been testing to display the list from my django into html select option but it didn't display . also I think I need to assign option value id in select option but I dont know where to start, If any expert could help Im glad for the response and thanks in advance.

> views.py

```
def passdata(request):


   datas = list(usertypes.objects.filter(
       permissions__user_id=request.GET['id']
   ).values_list('usertype', flat=True))

   user_list = {'result':datas} //how to display this to select option?
   return JsonResponse(user_list)
```

> Javascript ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function modal (post_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/passdata/',
        data: {
            'id': post_id
        },
        success: function(response){
            document.getElementById('selectvalue').innerHTML = response.result
            $("#editmodal").modal('show');
        }
    });
}
```

> modal select_option

```
<div class="card-content collapse show">
   <div class="card-body">
      <div class="form-group">

         <select multiple="multiple"  size="10" class="duallistbox">
            {% for result in result %}
            <option value="1" id="selectvalue">{{result}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
         </select>

      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are not creating new select options but instead writing all return values as text in one select option

Comment: @iklinac it just an example inorder to view the modal, I've updated my select option above but don't know how to return the list value

Comment: @iklinac can you provie solution or idea why the list didnot return even I'm using loop in select option?

Comment: Hi ,what does `response` has in it ? Can you add op of that in your asked question?

Comment: @Swati thanks for your response , I just want to display the list of my JsonResponse into my select option , but the list did not display, please help me

Comment: @Swati I've been updated my question above thanks for the response

Comment: Hi you are adding option inside option instead can you try like this -> `$(".duallistbox").html(response.result)` and see what happens .

Comment: @Swati hi thanks for your response, it is okay? to pass the class in option instead of select? like this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6owcQ.jpg) and javascript [javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoqFd.jpg) and the problem is the result it doesn't separate the value in option [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ExeV.jpg)

Comment: let me know op of `response.result` i.e : do`alert(response.result)` and see what it shows  so that i can create demo code .

Comment: @Swati thank you! so much , this is the result "super admin, admin,financial" the alert [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYvyG.jpg) and code [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol608.jpg)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222253/discussion-between-swati-and-d-jason).

Comment: @Swati I have a message

Answer (score 0):

As already commented your frontend is off, you are not creating new select options but instead writing all return values as text in one select option

---

give select and id

```
<select multiple="multiple"  size="10" class="duallistbox" id="someid" >
```

and fix script something in a line of following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function modal (post_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/passdata/',
        data: {
            'id': post_id
        },
        success: function(response){
            var modal_select = $('#someid')
            // remove previous select options
            modal_select.empty()
            // iterate result array and create select options
            $.each(response.result, function(index, value){
                modal_select.append(new Option(value, value))
            })
            $("#editmodal").modal('show');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response but still it doesn't show the list :(

Comment: should I remove the option in select option? it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/uelfo.jpg

Comment: Still the list not show Im getting this error "modal is not defined" need help , https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGP9W.jpg